# Atom.io Download not working: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.

Tags: atom-editor

When I try to download Atom from Atom.io, I get this error message:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with 
it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>
releases/untagged-2abd5a23b4430027c837/atom-mac.zip
</Key>
<RequestId>98BB6E3B14114B49</RequestId>
<HostId>
Os6+3SN9TYjh70tPusdHD1Ne2vpnDROISBJLZsCSaS0EfKhq6Q3qePRBbya62xoS9fP2irq+tf4=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have no idea what's wrong, this has never happened before. Please let me know what I need to change in order to download Atom! Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it is fixed, I just went back to the website and it worked. Magic!